# Running a UNC path using PSexec through CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, psexec

I got this code below, it will run the *LS-PrePost-3.0-Win32_setup.exe* using cmd.
My psexec is in c:\psexec. And I put put my batch file and the exe file in the same folder.

```
c:\psexec\psexec -d \\%%M  cmd /c start /wait "%~dp0LS-PrePost-3.0-Win32_setup.exe" /quiet /silent /norestart
```

My code seems does nothing. It execute the code but the exe file didnt run the the remote PC.

Edit: I changed the directory of Psexec.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something like

```
c:\psexec\psexec \\%%M -d -c "%~dp0LS-PrePost-3.0-Win32_setup.exe" /quiet /silent /norestart
```

- As you are not waiting (`-d`) you don't need the `start /wait`
- As you are starting a executable file not an internal command, you don't need the `cmd /c`.
- The file is executed in the remote machine, so, it must be available in the remote machine. Copy it (`-c`)

From `psexec` help

```
 -c         Copy the specified program to the remote system for
            execution. If you omit this option the application
            must be in the system path on the remote system.
 -d         Don't wait for process to terminate (non-interactive).
 cmd        Name of application to execute.
 arguments  Arguments to pass (note that file paths must be
            absolute paths on the target system).
```

Comment: I used CMD because the file in located in a shared folder. What I know is you cant execute exe file from shared drive using psexe. Have edited my post above

Comment: @RegieBaguio, you are using `%~dp0` to resolve to a path in the local machine, not to a path in the remote machine. The remote machine needs a path valid for the remote file system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pushd and popd to pass the the command through psexec for UNC paths.

```
    psexec.exe //FQDN -d cmd /c "pushd \\UNCFOLDER\ && file2execute.exe && popd"
```